# Why is my method not running all my when the button is pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, uibutton

I am trying to write a method that will allow me to buy an Upgrade when a button is pressed. However, what tends to happen is that once I press the button, the `buyShiny()` method only completely runs once. Afterwards it will still do `mainScript.coins -= coins` but nothing else.

The only way for the code to run reliably is if I write the same code for every upgrade I have. Although this works, I'm trying to have as little lines as possible.

problematic code:

```
public void buyUpgrade(int level, int maxLevel, Text levelTxt, double cost, double costScale, double affectedValue,
                           double UpGScale, Text PriceTxt)
    {
        if (level >= maxLevel)
        {
            level = maxLevel;
        }
        else if (level < maxLevel)
        {
            mainScript.coins -= cost;
            affectedValue *= UpGScale;
            cost *= costScale;
            PriceTxt.text = "Research\n" + shinyShellsCost.ToString("F2");
            level++;
            levelTxt.text = level + "x";
        }
    }

    public void buyShiny()
    {
        if(mainScript.coins >= shinyShellsCost)
        {
            buyUpgrade(shinyShellsLvl, shinyShellsMaxLvl, shinyShellsLvlTxt, shinyShellsCost, 1.06, mainScript.shellPrice, 1.1, shinyShellsPriceToReschTxt);
        }
    }
```

working code:

```
    public void buyShinyShell()
    {
        if(mainScript.coins >= shinyShellsCost)
        {
            if(shinyShellsLvl >= shinyShellsMaxLvl)
            {
                shinyShellsLvl = shinyShellsMaxLvl;
            }
            else if(shinyShellsLvl < shinyShellsMaxLvl)
            {
                mainScript.coins -= shinyShellsCost;
                mainScript.shellPrice *= 1.1;
                shinyShellsCost *= 1.06;
                shinyShellsPriceToReschTxt.text = "Research\n" + shinyShellsCost.ToString("F2");
                shinyShellsLvl++;
                shinyShellsLvlTxt.text = shinyShellsLvl + "x";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess by `not working` you refer to your according fields not being changed.

You are passing in **value** types (`int`, `double`) so any changes you make to the parameters inside a method will not affect the actual fields in your class at all! Nothing on the outside will be aware of what happened inside the method so you are always passing in the same values again -> Seems that nothing happens.

Your second version works because there you are directly manipulating the actual fields of your class.

---

To avoid that you can use the [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword for every parameter you are going to change within the method like

```
public void buyUpgrade(ref int level, int maxLevel, Text levelTxt, ref double cost, double costScale, ref double affectedValue, double UpGScale, Text PriceTxt)
{
    if (level >= maxLevel)
    {
        level = maxLevel;
    }
    else if (level < maxLevel)
    {
        mainScript.coins -= cost;
        affectedValue *= UpGScale;
        cost *= costScale;
        PriceTxt.text = "Research\n" + shinyShellsCost.ToString("F2");
        level++;
        levelTxt.text = level + "x";
    }
}

public void buyShiny()
{
    if(mainScript.coins >= shinyShellsCost)
    {
        buyUpgrade(ref shinyShellsLvl, shinyShellsMaxLvl, shinyShellsLvlTxt, ref shinyShellsCost, 1.06, ref mainScript.shellPrice, 1.1, shinyShellsPriceToReschTxt);
    }
}
```

Now you are forcing to treat these passed values like a reference and will update whatever value you pass in via the `ref`